# "\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}" Does it have an article counterparet?

Tags: fonts, article

In the beamer, the default font of math formulas are with no serif. If we want the formulas to have serif like the default font in article, we need to use

```
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
```

.  But this command only works for beamer. Does the command have a counterpart for article, i.e. let the default font of math formulas in articles be with no serif?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you for your comment! I think the `\usepackage[cm]{sfmath}` command is precisely what I was looking for.